# How can I combine two versions of redux-form in one store?

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have a lot of forms and want to gradually, one by one, migrate my forms  from 5 to 6 version of redux-form.
I have figured out how to manage dependencies but how can I combine two versions of reducers with one store key `form`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `getFormState` config property when connecting the form to redux and point it to the corresponding key in the state tree.

When combining the reducer, include both versions but at different keys (I'm not sure how you are managing the the dependencies but you should get the jist):

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducerV5 } from 'redux-form-v5'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

const reducers = {
  // ... your other reducers here
  form: formReducer,
  formV5: formReducerV5
}
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers)
const store = createStore(reducer)
```

Then to use the v5 reducer you override the default `form` key:

```
const yourFormContainer = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm'
  getFormState: state => state.formV5
})(YourForm);
```

Forms that have been migrated to v6 can just use the default `getFormState` behaviour and eventually you will be able to remove the old reducer.

Comment: Whoa, that's never something I considered anyone doing, but that is the correct answer. 